# Save a file to the SD-card

Tags: java, android

.txt file need save in SD-card.

```
Save("n" + String.valueOf(key) + ".txt");

 private void Save(String FileName){
         File fileName = null;
         String sdState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();

         if (sdState.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
             File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
             fileName = new File(sdDir, "FlyNote/"+FileName);
             } else {
                 fileName = context.getCacheDir();
             }
         if (!fileName.exists())
             fileName.mkdirs();
         try {
             FileWriter f = new FileWriter(fileName);
             f.write(editText2.getText().toString());
             f.flush();
             f.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {

         }
     }
```

But in the SD-card file saves as a folder.
Folder "n5.txt" and other...

Comment: because you use fileName.mkdirs(); which create directory of file name if it does not exists.

Comment: fileName.mkdirs(); you are creating a directory.. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232148/how-to-read-data-from-a-sqllite-database-table/11232938#11232938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
File  dir= new File(sdDir.getAbsolutePath(), "FlyNote");
dir.mkdirs(); //CREATE DIR HERE
File  file = new File(dir, FileName);//CREATE FILE HERE
```

instead of

```
fileName = new File(sdDir, "FlyNote/"+FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you test for exists, you are searching if `Flynote/Filename` exists or not and if it doesnt exist you create one using `mkdirs`.

`fileName.mkdirs()` makes a directory with the name of that file. Hence you find the error. Your `mkdirs` should only be for `Flynote` and not `Flynote/+FileName`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If you are aiming for a file, why r u using "mkdir" that makes a directory not a file.

**This code is to create a file:**

```
File f = new File("/sdcard/n5.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferdWriter(fw);
bw.write("Hello");
```

**To check if the Folder exist...**

```
File f = new File("/sdcard/myfolder");
if (f.exists()){

   // do what u want

   }
else{
       // doesnt exists
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the methods given here is good... You could also use this following code:

```
    public static void addToFile(String file,String message){

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        fos.write(("\n"+message).getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here "File" is a string which contains the path to your file eg: File = "/sdcard/parentPath/FileName.txt" and "message" is for obvious the message that you want to enter into the file. (considering the file contains txt contents)